# How to map the IP address of docker container to another container dynamically

Tags: tomcat, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I have few docker containers running in a host. I have a scenario where i need to map the IP address of one container to the configuration file available in another container. I know that i can get the IP address of a container using the **docker inspect [container]** command. I assumes the IP address is assigned dynamically every time i restart the container. So every time i need to change this IP address in another container. Is it possible to have a static ip for container or can i use the ip address of the host instead of ip address of the container. I am new to docker world.

Also i have a case where i need to map the IP address to a container that is running in another host. Example, i have a redis container running in HostA and tomcat container running in HostB. In order to communicate with redis from tomcat, i need to map the ip address and port of redis in the tomcat container. how this can be achieved in docker ?

Comment: You almost certainly do not need actual IP addresses, that's a horrible way to link stuff.    Use container linking -- it is baked in.

Comment: i have a property file in tomcat container and i have to provide the ip address of redis in that. tomcat reads this property during startup and connects with redis. So how linking will solve this prob ? does linking container using alias means hostname for the container ?

Comment: @Jugi yes it's hostname (or alias like i said in my answer) and you can check `/etc/hosts` - [here is example](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/#/updating-the-etchosts-file) - It's something like `localhost` as alias for `127.0.0.1`. In your case tomcat `/etc/hosts` will have ip address for `redis`. Something like: `172.17.0.5  redis`

Comment: @VladoDemcak. thanks a lot..

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** linking container with `--link` parameter is marked as legacy [enter link description here](http://docs.docker.com/network/links)

> Warning: The --link flag is a legacy feature of Docker. It may
>   eventually be removed. Unless you absolutely need to continue using
>   it, **we recommend that you use user-defined networks to facilitate
>   communication between two containers instead of using --link**. One
>   feature that user-defined networks do not support that you can do with
>   --link is sharing environmental variables between containers. However, you can use other mechanisms such as volumes to share environment
>   variables between containers in a more controlled way.

You need docker network. Examples below are from official documentation but here it's in few lines:

First create docker network eg.:

docker network create `--driver` bridge you
now you can run containers like in the documentation - **Linking containers in user-defined networks**:

```
docker run --network=your_netowrk -itd --name=container4 --link container5:c5 image
docker run --network=your_netowrk -itd --name=container5 --link container4:c4 image
```

---

**Original answer:**

You can run **linked** containers like in the documentation - [Linking containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/#/linking-containers-in-user-defined-networks):

```
docker run -itd --name=container4 --link container5:c5 image
docker run -itd --name=container5 --link container4:c4 image
```

and ping second container **by alias** `(c5)`:

```
docker attach container4

/ # ping -w 4 c5
PING c5 (172.25.0.5): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.25.0.5: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.070 ms
```

so you can see it's possible to ping second container **with alias - not with IP address**.

*To your second Quesiton:* It's possible if you have `redis` and `tomcat` and they know IP addresses of each other (and they are accessible because they are in some network), so this is almost all about the configuration of network.

Comment: Holy crap, I'm not sure that you need a custom network to link 2 containers together.   Google docker container linking.   It's built in.

Comment: @user2105103 Thanks, you are right I didn't know it's built in and for 2 containers it's "useless" to create custom network.

Comment: linking is marked as legacy -> reverted answer with user defined network

Answer (score 1):

As Vlado pointed out, you should access your containers by hostname and allow Docker to manage that mapping those names to IP addresses. There are two options for this [legacy links](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/#/connect-with-the-linking-system) and links in [user defined networks](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/#linking-containers-in-user-defined-networks). Both descriptions are worth reading, but his paragraph outlines the difference between the two approaches *(emphasis mine)*

> Please note that while creating container4, we linked to a container named container5 which is not created yet. That is one of the differences in behavior between the legacy link in default bridge network and the new link functionality in user defined networks. **The legacy link is static in nature and it hard-binds the container with the alias and it doesn’t tolerate linked container restarts.** While the new link functionality in user defined networks are dynamic in nature and supports linked container restarts including tolerating ip-address changes on the linked container.

Based on your [next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40662254/is-it-possible-to-create-container-in-multiple-host-using-a-single-docker-compos), if you want to run containers on multiple hosts, you will probably want to set up an [overlay network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/). Those definitely don't support legacy links.

The official docs have good examples, including what commands to run, to create links and user defined networks.